# Почему node js не видет тело запроса?

Tags: node.js, express

Есть код на nodejs, он полностью рабочий.

```
const express = require('express')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const app = express()

dotenv.config()

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.use(express.json());
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log("work")
})
app.post('/auth', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
})

try {
    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log('SERVER STARTED ON PORT ' + PORT))
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
}
```

При отправке пост запроса на "/auth" я получаю просто "{}" хотя в теле запроса указываю json.
В загаловке запроса Content-Type указан как application/json
Тело запроса: {"asdas": "asd21"} (просто как пример)
В чем проблема? Почему он не видет тело запроса? (даже если отправляю просто текст)

Отправляю запрос через программу "Postman"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Раздел "Headers" запроса:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите как конкретно вы отправляете запрос

Comment: Дополнил вопрос. Там показал как отправляю

Comment: Так порт 300 или 5000?

Comment: Если он не сможет из .env взять порт 300 то будет использовать 5000.
Это я так сделал, все работает на порту 300. И запрос я отправляю когда сервер работает на 300-м порту.

Comment: У меня этот код работает? Можно где-то в postman-е посмотреть что он реально отправил?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzieC.png

Answer (score 0):

Код полностью правильный.
Проблема была в программе "Postman".
Спасибе этому [человеку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/190728/alexey-ten)